# Changing a result from p:autoComplete's completeMethod before using it

Tags: jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

I'm implementing a dialog for registering an address. In the street name field, I'm using PrimeFaces' `<p:autoComplete>` tag to help the user find the name of their street. The `completeMethod` works as expected, but to avoid confusion between similar street names I would like the drop-down list to also include the municipality the given street is in, for instance on the format `"<street name>, <municipality name>"`.

I don't want the municipality name to be included in the actual field, so I've concluded that I need a method that performs some sort of string manipulation (substring using the position of the first comma, for instance), but I can't figure out where such a method would be called from. I've had a look through the PrimeFaces documentation, but I haven't been able to find anything that would allow me to do this. Is this at all possible in `<p:autoComplete>`? Alternatively, is there another autocomplete implementation which supports this, or would I have to implement my own javascript component?

EDIT: This is what the xhtml code I'm using looks like:

```
<div class="form-group row required">
    <h:outputLabel value="#{msgs['@common.mailingAddress']}" for="address" styleClass="col-xs-12"/>
    <p:autoComplete
        id="address"
        name="address"
        size="50"
        maxlength="50"
        styleClass="col-xs-12 street-name"
        label="#{msgs['@common.search']}"
        disabled="#{not configurationController.cardCtrl.editable}"
        value="#{configurationController.cardCtrl.selected.address}"
        required="true"
        completeMethod="#{configurationController.cardCtrl.autoCompleteTest}">
        <f:validator binding="#{onlyLettersOrDigitsValidator}"/>
    </p:autoComplete>
    <h:message id="addressMessage" for="address" styleClass="inline-error inline-error-small"/>
</div>
```

The `autoCompleteTest` method in the controller is as follows:

```
public List autoCompleteTest(String input) {
    AddressSearch addressSearch = AddressSearch.builder()
            .streetName(input)
            .municipality(municipality.getName())
            .maxResultsPerPage(10)
            .build();
    return addressesToStreetNames(mapService.addressSearch(addressSearch).getAddresses());
}
```

With a helper method `addressesToStreetNames` which takes a list of Address objects and returns an `ArrayList<String>` containing those addresses' street names.

EDIT2: Based on suggestions in the comments, I tried setting `itemValue` and `itemLabel` to different values, to see if that had any effect. The new xhtml looks like the above, with the addition of the following three lines:

```
var="address"
itemValue="#{address.streetName}"
itemLabel="#{configurationController.cardCtrl.formatAddress(address.streetName, address.postTown)}"
```

The autoCompleteTest method now also returns the Address object directly rather than a String representation of the street name, so that these fields are available. The formatAddress method is simply `return streetName + ', ' + postTown;`
This causes the dropdown list to look how I want it to look, but when I click an item it still inserts the whole string with both street name and post town/municipality into the text field (and in fact, before I've written anything, the text field already contains ", ").

Comment: Could you share your code how you are using the autocomplete?

Comment: @AshishMathew Code added!

Comment: Why is the custom content example in the showcase not an option: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but from what I could tell none of the examples inserted any text in the fields that was different from what was selected in the dropdown menu (for instance, if I selected "Afternoon" from the list, the text that ended up in the field was just that - "Afternoon"). What I'm after would be if the dropdown menu item said, for instance, "Afternoon theme" but only the "Afternoon" part ended up in the text field.

Comment: @GlossyMage That's exactly what the custom content example demonstrates. You have to use `itemValue` and `itemLabel` attributes to show a different label for a value.

Comment: @AshishMathew Ah, I see! That seems to be a step in the right direction, but I'm not quite there yet. I set `itemLabel=address.streetName + address.postTown` and `itemValue=address.postalCode` (just to see if it would actually work), but it still inserts `address.streetName + address.postTown` into the text field, ignoring itemValue.

Comment: You might need a converter....

Comment: I've added a converter, and the converter's `getAsString` method gets called, with itemValue as a parameter. However, this doesn't appear to change anything in front end, and the text that ends up in the field is still taken directly from itemLabel.